# Conditional in Array

Tags: php, html

If the value `qtd` is greater than `5` appears OK, otherwise, OPS.
and
If the value `qtd` is greater than 5 appears an image 1, otherwise image 2.

```
if ($aluno->qtd > 5) {
    $numeral = "OK"; 
    $image = "<imgsrc="link_da_image111" />"; 
} else {
    $numeral = "OPS";
    $image = "<img src="link_da_image222" />";
}
$table = new html_table();
$table->attributes = array("class" => "table table-hover table-condensed table-striped table-users slide_7");
foreach($alunos as $aluno) {
    $row = new html_table_row();
    $row->cells = array( $aluno->firstname . ' ' . $aluno->lastname, $aluno->user_picture, $aluno->qtd, $aluno->firstname . ' ' . $aluno->lastname, $numeral, $image, );
    $table->data[] = $row;
}
echo html_writer::table($table);
```

I would like the result to be something like this

```
Joan       --- 34   ---- OK
Marr       --- 2     ---- OPS
Richar    --- 34    ---- OK 
Otvr       --- 1      ---- OPS
```

Comment: Check your question, it's pretty messed up, re-format it

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement needs to be inside the `foreach` loop so that it can refer to the `$aluno` variable that's set for each element of `$alunos`.

```
$table = new html_table();
$table->attributes = array("class" => "table table-hover table-condensed table-striped table-users slide_7");
foreach($alunos as $aluno) {
    if ($aluno->qtd > 5) {
        $numeral = "OK"; 
        $image = "<imgsrc="link_da_image111" />"; 
    } else {
        $numeral = "OPS";
        $image = "<img src="link_da_image222" />";
    }
    $row = new html_table_row();
    $row->cells = array( $aluno->firstname . ' ' . $aluno->lastname, $aluno->user_picture, $aluno->qtd, $aluno->firstname . ' ' . $aluno->lastname, $numeral, $image, );
    $table->data[] = $row;
}
echo html_writer::table($table);
```

Comment: Dude, that's exactly what I needed, THANK YOU!
Sorry for the mess, it was my first post here and I'm a beginner. I'll get better.
Hugs !